# How to transform elements of a list into one string?

Tags: python

community,

I have a list, that consists of different strings (sentences, words...) I would like to join them all together to one string.
I tried:

```
kafka = ['Das ist ein schöner Tag.', '>>I would like some ice cream and a big cold orange juice!',...]
''.join(kafka) #but strings stay the same as before
```

Comment: And did you assign the result of `''.join(kafka)` to anything? It won't have any effect if it's just on a line by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
kafka = ['Das ist ein schöner Tag.', '>>I would like some ice cream and a big cold orange juice!',...]
s = ''.join(kafka)
```

`s` now contains your concatenated string.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are on the right track, but you need to assign the join operation to a new variable or use it directly. the original list won't be affected.

concatenate them with or without any spaces in between:

```
no_spaces = ''.join(kafka)
with_spaces = ' '.join(kafka)

print no_spaces
print with_spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that

```
''.join(kafka)
```

returns the new string without modifying kafka. Try:

```
my_string = ''.join(kafka)
```

And if you want spaces between sentences then use:

```
my_string = ' '.join(kafka)
```

Answer (score 0):

`''.join(kafka)` returns a string. To make use of it, store it into a variable:

```
joined = ''.join(kafka)
print joined
```

Note: you may want to join with a space `' '` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can join it using ,

Assuming your list is

`['Das ist ein schöner Tag.', '>>I would like some ice cream and a big cold orange juice!']`

```
>>> kafka = ['Das ist ein schöner Tag.', '>>I would like some ice cream and a big cold orange juice!']
>>>' '.join(kafka)
```

Output :

```
'Das ist ein sch\xf6ner Tag. >>I would like some ice cream and a big cold orange juice!'
```